# Strange value of the constant multiplication

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

#define P d2 + 2

int main()
{
    int d2 = 4;

    cout << P * 2;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Why this code return 8 instead of 12?
When I cout the P, it has 6 value.

Comment: operator precedence? When writing macros use `(` brackets as much as you can.

Comment: Change to `#define P (d2 + 2)`

Comment: 4 + 2 * 2 = 8.  simple enough.

Answer (score 3):

The C (and C++) preprocessor, which runs before the compiler, does a strict replacement when using directives `#include` and `#define`. In other words, after the preprocessor runs, all the compiler sees is

```
cout << d2 + 2 * 2;
```

You should try

```
#define P (d2 + 2)
```

or even better avoid macros altogether.

Comment: You forgot another pair of brackets in the macro definiton sample.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Yes, the macro could benefit from more brackets if d2 was an argument. In other words, if we had `#define P(x) x + 2`, then it would be safer as `#define P(x) ((x) + 2)`. But in this case an `inline int P(int x) { return x + 2;}` would be even better.

Answer (score 1):

You forget braces. Macros are directly replaced in code. So your statement does:

```
cout << d2 + 2 * 2
```

Which is `d2 + 4`.

Edit your macro to

```
#define P (d2 + 2)
```